# Keep Getting Accuracy zero when training Neural Network - Python

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm new to neural network and I'm trying to build and train a neural network where I can predict the **int_rate**. The data looks like this:

```
    loan_amnt   annual_inc  emp_length  int_rate
       10000    38000.0    5.600882      12.40
       13750    17808.0    5.600882      28.80
       26100    68000.0    10.00000      20.00
```

after normalizing the data:

```
array([[0.23076923, 0.01141827, 0.44444444],
       [0.32692308, 0.00535096, 0.44444444],
       [0.64358974, 0.02043269, 1.        ],
       ...,
       [0.23076923, 0.04507212, 1.        ],
       [0.43846154, 0.0390625 , 0.44444444],
       [0.14102564, 0.02103365, 1.        ]])
```

and after splitting the data to features and target(the target is int_rate) I got these shapes:

`print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_val.shape, Y_test.shape)`

output: `(693, 3) (148, 3) (149, 3) (693,) (148,) (149,)`

After that, I started building my model:

```
        model = Sequential([
     Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,)),
     Dense(32, activation='relu'),
     Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
     ])
```

Then compiled it using mean-square-error as my loss function:

```
          model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['acc'])
```

Finally, fitting and training the model:

```
          hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

When training:

```
    Train on 693 samples, validate on 148 samples

    Epoch 1/100
    693/693 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 158.9353 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 
    188.9402 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00

    Epoch 2/100
    693/693 [==============================] - 0s 51us/step - loss: 158.9353 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - 
    val_loss: 
    188.9402 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

And all the Epoch have the same numbers and accuracy which is **zero**. Is there a way I can solve it?

Comment: Try normalising all your data between zero and one.  emp_length is a considerably smaller number than loan ammount

Comment: I have normalized it buy using ` preprocessing.MinMaxScaler() ` and ` min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int_rate` variable that you are trying to predict is continuous, not discrete. This means you have a regression problem. The `accuracy` metric is for classification problems only, so it does not make any sense for regression (that is why it is always zero).

Also since you are using the `sigmoid` activation at the output, the network can only predict values in the `[0, 1]` range, so to use this activation you have to normalize the target data (the `int_rate` variable).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're trying to predict a continuous value, you have two choices to do so, either you don't use a **sigmoid** at the end of your model but a **linear** or **no activation**, the model will then output a single value. As other suggested you can normalize your data if you know the boundaries and leave the sigmoid.

In either case, accuracy may not be a perfect metrics to use in case of regression. Usually it doesn't mean anything, **MSE** is a good enough metric.